# "Invalid field path" error while fetching image from url in firestore database

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch an image from Firestore Database to my android applcation.The image url is stored in a collection named "Gestures".And the collection has documents each consisting of image url.When I am trying to fetch the image url its showing "Invalid field path" error.But what other url can I use?
The database is as shown:[image: Firestore Database]
Please help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
 public void loadGestureImage(){
            DocumentReference documentReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("Gestures").document(G1);
            documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        DocumentSnapshot doc=task.getResult();
                        String img_url=(doc.get("https:/drive.google.com/file/d/1h4YIvVKzdMEAj_EuZbYPJyFRVYb90CA7/view?usp=sharing")).toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(img_url).into(imageView1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the wrong field inside your firebase. First of all, you need to change the document call from G1 to "G1".

Another thing you need do is to change fetching of Img property from

```
doc.get("https:/drive.google.com/file/d/1h4YIvVKzdMEAj_EuZbYPJyFRVYb90CA7/view?usp=sharing")
```

to

```
doc.get("Img")
```

So complete solution to your problem should be something like this:

```
 public void loadGestureImage(){
        DocumentReference documentReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("Gestures").document("G1");
        documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot doc=task.getResult();
                    String img_url=(doc.get("Img")).toString();
                    Picasso.get().load(img_url).into(imageView1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.But I tried the above changes in code,still the image is not loaded in the application.

Comment: The image doesn't load for you, because the URL doesn't point to the direct image location. You can only load direct URL to an image to the Glide library. For your example, you need to replace URL for an image with this URL:

https://doc-10-90-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/5raqjs3em9na7svh9d4i34hpm2chch92/hdqj33gfhgk2d7a9d2uvbg8o8d51m6d0/1580198400000/01523221432119945004/13131987331635234592/1h4YIvVKzdMEAj_EuZbYPJyFRVYb90CA7?h=10910788008166000682&authuser=0&nonce=83kvo00ifedjm&user=13131987331635234592&hash=5psbucfhg1bjn9sfn8i3nh4sdtjh4kpp

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use the name of the document field to get the value assigned to it.  It seems that you're trying to get the value of the URL using the value of the URL itself, which is rather odd.

```
String img_url = doc.getString("Img");
```

I will also point out that your URL is malformed.  It's not valid, and it won't load correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But even though I tried the above changes suggested,the image is still not getting displayed.Can you tell me how do I form the correct url of image?

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, the URL you show is malformed and will not load.